# GAP Integrated Development Environment

Tags: gap

Is there any fancy editor of GAP code or even some environment dedicated to it? I've been using Notepad++ for this purpose but it seems only to color the syntax. I would like to have more developmental  features.

Comment: You mean like a button or shortcut to put in a "read" command in GAP?

Comment: Personally, I do not like fancy editors, and I use vi (which you might not have heard of) for everything, but I am very old fashioned! I don't think this question is about mathematics.

Comment: Sage contains GAP, you might do better looking for IDEs for that - you can run it in a jupyter notebook for example

Comment: For Windows, Notepad++ is the best choice (https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#8.3) although it's not an IDE. As for Jupyter, there is a Jupyter kernel for GAP as well (https://gap-packages.github.io/JupyterKernel/), and it is redistributed with the latest GAP release (although it's also not an IDE).   For Linux, GAP has some nice setup for vim and emacs, adding some IDE features.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what kind of features you are looking for... ?

Comment: Another page with information about GAP mode in some editors is https://github.com/gap-system/gap/wiki/Syntax-Highlighting-GAP. GAP also has a Jupyter kernel, you can try it e.g. at https://github.com/gap-system/try-gap-in-jupyter or https://github.com/OpenDreamKit/gap-demos

Comment: Does IDE mean an environment where we can copy and paste codes and run them to get results? I was able to open Jupyter Kernel for GAP and was able to check syntax, but I could not get an answer to my question, which was some generators for the normalizer of a subgroup in S_5.

Comment: @AgentSmith you should be able to get answer in Jupyter. Try it at https://github.com/gap-system/try-gap-in-jupyter, please let me know what does not work! (I haven't seen your comment without an `@` ping - please make sure you ping me in your reply).